# Are there any difference calling `run.db` once and multiple times in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

Are there any difference calling `run.db` once:

```
val dbAction3 = for {
  res1 <- dbAction1
  res2 <- dbAction2(res1)
} yield res2

val res3 = db.run(dbAction3)
```

and multiple times:

```
val res3 = for {
  res1 <- db.run(dbAction1)
  res2 <- db.run(dbAction2(res1))
} yield res2
```

As far as I understand, there is no difference unless we use `transactionally` in the first one.

Comment: This question is missing so much crucial information. Please show anything that is available in scope with types. Specifically what types are (or you think that they are) these db actions, and what type is db. Does this code compile, or the code you are referencing here? Because as is, this code does not, obviously. And without knowing more info on what is expected to be in scope, this question has too little information to figure out on my own.

Comment: Perhaps this? https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.2.0/dbio.html#

Comment: I don't say it compiles. I was trying to abstract the real question from unnecessary details. I guess, by type, you mean read queries like `select` and write queries like `insert` and `update`.  We can evaluate the question for different type combinations. For example,  both are read queries or both are write queries or one of them is read while the other one is write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observable effect of the two is the same, but they execute in different ways. The first version creates a single query that is passed to the database whereas the second creates two separate database queries.

The first version gives greater potential for optimisation if there is any commonality between the two actions. (e.g. if both actions use the same tables/views). A good database might be able to combine or re-order operations for greater efficiency in a way that would not be possible with separate queries.

The second version incurs the overhead of two database operations and uses the `Future` mechanism to serialise them rather than internal database mechanisms, so is likely to be less efficient.

There are no downsides to the first version and it might execute more efficiently, so that is the "better" choice. But it does depend on the particular database implementation so there may be cases where the second version is faster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a few follow-ups. Think about a monolith system that you try to decompose into microservices step by step. In that case, using Future (the second option) seems necessary to me if we do not need `transactionally` because it will make calling the external services easier. Also, think about larger `for`s with 10-20 queries, are we sure that Slick creates an optimized single query?

Comment: Also, if the first one creates a single query (I use PostgreSQL btw), why do we even need `transactionally`? PostgresSQL already provides that (See the first sentences in [this doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/tutorial-transactions.html)).

Comment: I should have been more precise and said "operation" rather than "query", since even a single Slick action can contain multiple operations (e.g. `DBIO.sequence`). Your specific operations takes the results from `dbAction1` and passes it to `dbAction2` so there must be two separate operations. So without `transactionally` something might happen between `dbAction1` and `dbAction2` either way.